# How to paint selected point on 3D surface?

Tags: delphi, teechart

How can I paint selected point on TeeChart 3D Surface?

[image: Example]

Comment: I tried to find standard methods or properties to show selected point, but this series don't have this. Other way, but wrong, is add two line-series, but they can not move on z axis (and x axis, if perpendicular). I don't have source code of TeeChart, to look how does it implemented at Surface Nearest Tool.

Answer (score 1):

- **If you want to highlight the cell below the mouse**, you can use the `TSurfaceNearestTool` to highlight a `TSurfaceSeries` cell like in the example at "All Features\Welcome !\Tools\Surface Nearest" in the Features Demo program:

[image: SurfaceNearest]

The Features Demo program (Tee9New.exe) is shipped with the installation of the component, and you can alternatively download the "TeeChart compiled demo" [here](https://www.steema.com/download/vcl).

You just have to create the tool and assign a surface to it. Ie:

```
uses TeeSurfaceTool, TeeSurfa;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.AddSeries(TSurfaceSeries).FillSampleValues;

  (Chart1.Tools.Add(TSurfaceNearestTool) as TSurfaceNearestTool).Series:=Chart1[0];
end;
```

- **If you know the ValueIndex of the cell to highlight**, you can just change the `ValueColor[ValueIndex]` property. Ie:

```
uses TeeSurfa, TeeTools;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin    
  Chart1.Aspect.Zoom:=80;
  Chart1.Chart3DPercent:=100;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TSurfaceSeries) as TSurfaceSeries do
  begin
    FillSampleValues;

    UseColorRange:=false;
    UsePalette:=false;
    for i:=0 to Count-1 do
      if (i mod 2 = 0) then
        ValueColor[i]:=clGreen;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I need to programmatically highlight a point, but not by the mouse

Comment: I've edited my answer. See the second part of the same.